# Using jQuery to make sidebar same height as content

Tags: jquery

For example: https://anxietyintheclassroom.org/school-system/resources-for-school-personnel/how-to-work-with-your-colleagues/

My jquery code is below.  It seems when I SHIFT refresh, the sidebar is the full height, but sometimes when loading the page, the sidebar has white space below it, and is not full height.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var contentheight = jQuery('.storycontent').outerHeight(true);
jQuery('.page #sidebar').height( contentheight );
jQuery('.page-template-inside-page #sidebar').css("height", 
contentheight);
jQuery('.page-template-inside-page .storycontent').css("height", 
contentheight);
});
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
var contentheight = jQuery('.storycontent').outerHeight(true);
jQuery('.page #sidebar').height( contentheight );
jQuery('.page-template-inside-page #sidebar').css("height", 
contentheight);*


jQuery('.page-template-inside-page .storycontent').css("height", 
contentheight);
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a classic problem where the javascript renders as soon as the DOM is ready but all the resources have not downloaded, which could include the images. In such a scenario the calculations happen with initial height, but as the resources start loading there is a mismatch of height between the two elements.

Try to use:

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
    // your code goes here
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Its generally easier to debug if you shrink your code and follow DRY (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself) principles.

Since #sidebar is an ID, it should be in the page just once, so 
`.page #sidebar'` and `.page-template-inside-page #sidebar` refer to the same 
element, if you have two different elements with the id #sidebar it could be part of your problem, consider using a class instead.

if you write your code in a more compact manner it could be written like this.

```
jQuery(()=>{
  function setHeight(){
    jQuery(".page-template-inside-page").find(".storycontent, #sidebar").css({
      height: jQuery('.storycontent, #sidebar').outerHeight(true)
    });
  };
  jQuery(window).resize(setHeight);
  setHeight();
});
```

When written this way, you can see that you taking the outer height of and setting it to the height, this is not the same value. outterHeight includes margins and padding, height dose not. It also doesn't take into account that the sidebar might be longer

The code could be more robustly written like this.

```
jQuery(()=>{
  function setHeight(){
    //use Math.max to get the height of the taller element
    const height = Math.max(
       jQuery("#sidebar").height(), 
       jQuery(".page-template-inside-page .storycontent").height()
    );
    //if you need to select more then one element, you can separate them with commas
    jQuery("#sidebar, .page-template-inside-page .storycontent").css({
      height: height
    });
  };
  jQuery(window).resize(setHeight); //call the setHeight function on resize
  setHeight(); //call the setHeight function when the document loads.
});
```

I don't have your html markup or css, if the elements are nested (one inside the other) ensure the inner element has no top or bottom padding.

PS. the question was about how to do it with jQuery... but it would be easier/faster to do it with pure css...
https://davidwalsh.name/flexbox-column